# Cannot load a collection of items into a listview box with 2 columns

Tags: c#, json, winforms

so I am creating a currency converter program that pulls live currency information for a boatload of countries from the cloud and displays the real time data in a listview box along with conversions.  I have everything set correctly in the business layer (using JSON) and when running, I successfully see the data.  So I am having trouble taking that data and loading it into a listview box.  Here is the code for the form...

```
    namespace BigBirtha
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ExchangeRateService exchangeRates;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            exchangeRates = new ExchangeRateService();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var exchange = exchangeRates.GetExchangeRates();
            countryListView.Items.AddRange(exchange.ToArray()); //Believe this is the issue
        }
    }
}
```

ExchangeRateService uses JSON and returns the rates through a list which works fine.  Pulls 172 items from the cloud and each item returns the countries CurrencyCode and Rate.

I simply want to take these items and populate them into a listview box named countryListView with 2 columns named countryHeader and rateHeader.

get the error code CS1503 Argument 1:  cannot convert from 'BigBirtha.models.ExchangeRate[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[]'

P.S.  If it helps, here is another class I created that helps pull the data.

```
    namespace BigBirtha
{
    class ExchangeRateService
    {
        private const string EXCHANGE_URL = ""; //removed this 
        public List<ExchangeRate> GetExchangeRates()
        {
            List<ExchangeRate> rates = new List<ExchangeRate>();

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var json = client.DownloadString(EXCHANGE_URL);
                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchangeRatesResponse>(json);

                foreach (var rate in response.Rates)
                {
                    var exchangeRate = new ExchangeRate
                    {
                        CurrencyCode = rate.Key,
                        Rate = rate.Value
                    };
                    rates.Add(exchangeRate);
                } 
            }
            return rates;
        }
    }
}
```

So have been given suggestions to try this code...

```
    var listViewItemsOfExchangeRates= new ListViewItem(exchange.ToArray();
    countryListView.Items.Add(listViewItemsOfExchangeRates);
```

Receieve the following error which is very similar....

```
CS1503 Argument 1:  cannot convert from `"System.Collections.Generic.List<BigBirtha.models.ExchangeRate>" to "string"`
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I guess, you need to show us the entire code you are working on. Namely the columns you are adding if any and what is the data type of each column you are adding - meaning if you are adding a checkbox and or a text box to the list view, if done through the winform designer , paste the designercode.cs corresponding to it. Also depending on what you have added you may need to `Override` the `ToString()` property on the exchange rates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly what it says , meaning you can only add a  collection of type `listItem` to your `listview` control and you are trying to add a collection of type `array`.

I would suggest you take a look at this MSDN article to set your data source for your list view control from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx

**Sample code based on MSDN article**

```
var listViewItemsOfExchangeRates= new ListViewItem(exchange.ToArray());
countryListView.Items.Add(listViewItemsOfExchangeRates);
```

Not tested, so please modify accordingly

**Edit based on comments - The above code is related to winforms**

Last I knew and worked on winforms, ListView does not support databinding. However tt's possible to databind new WPF ListBox. Or use a listBox instead

This article describes how to add databinding capability to custom control inherited from WinForms ListView: https://www.codeproject.com/kb/list/listview_databinding.aspx

Comment: Sorry for delay, just got around to testing.  So after trying this logic, I received a similar error.  Get the error code CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BigBirtha.models.ExchangeRate[]>' to 'String.'  I checked out the MSDN article, tried an alternative method and received the same error message.

Comment: yes, I guess, you need to show us the entire code you are working on. Namely the columns you are adding if any and what is the data type of each column you are adding - meaning if you are adding a checkbox and or a text box to the list view .

Comment: Sure, so the only thing on the GUI is a ListViewBox.  Nothing additional at this time.  In that ListViewBox, there are 2 columns for the Country Currency and the Rate.  Under the hood, in the ExchangeRateService class, when I run and highlight "return rates" at the bottom, there are 2 locals.  One which is "this" which refers to the URL for getting the data.  The second is named "rates" which returns 172 items which inside each has "CurrencyCode"(string) AND "Rate"(decimal).  Does that help?

Comment: Sure that is a good start, also is this WPF or winform project? ListView in each behaves differently

Comment: Sorry winform I assume as I am using Visual Studio 2015 and am using System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130562/discussion-between-js-godblessall-and-markfro).

Comment: Okay but I first off want to say thank you for being one of the solid mentors of this site!  One person posted code in which I responded the error their code caused and why it wouldn't work (he had like 14k reputation) so he deleted his code. You seem to be willing to work for a resolution which goes miles beyond!